# Current date with datetime

Tags: php

I have a vacation request form, I have a two date and time fields. Well one field is `start_date` and another is `end_date`. What I want is that when a user goes to create a request, in the field of `start_date` leave the current date and the time is 08:00, some help?

It should look like this:

```
Start Date: 28/02/2017 08:00
```

In the database is also as `DATETIME`

Comment: How are you executing the query? Are you wanting to set that datetime in PHP and pass it as a parameter, or to do it in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set time of any DateTime object with this method:

```
$start_date = (new DateTime)->setTime(8,0)->format('d/m/Y H:i');
```

Or if you are pulling the datetime from database as string:

```
$start_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $yourDateTime)
                  ->setTime(8,0)
                  ->format('d/m/Y H:i');
```

Comment: Yes! Works! but what if I want the current date and time?

Comment: @AlvaroRomanFranco if you want the current date and current time, just remove the `->setTime()` method from the first example